# Converting pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have to do EDA on dataframe but it's huge dataframe in pyspark I'm using toPandas() method to convert pyspark dataframe to python dataframe but it's taking to much time to convert as I know only python to do EDA needs some suggestions and pieces of code to do conversion easily.

Comment: Hi @Data_guy! Normally we expect a higher quality description in your title and description, please do the next time. 
Have you considered to do EDA on a [sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample.html) set of your data, or just [take](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.take.html) the top N rows of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

instead of converting to pandas on your Spark DF. This will be faster, easier and also the same syntax you are used to using with pandas.

Comment: df1  = df.toPandas() I'm doing right now how to use pyspark.pandas as per your suggestion for above conversion

Comment: try using to_pandas_on_spark() on your df. 

df1 = df.to_pandas_on_spark()